# Cannot install ibm-wdt V8.5

Tags: failed-installation, ibm-wdt

When I want to install IBM WDT V8.5 via MarketPlace, I get this error:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Failed to transfer artifact canonical: osgi.bundle,com.ibm.websphere.v85.core,1.0.200.v20170613_0418.
Connection to http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/updates/wdt/oxygen_comp/repository/plugins/com.ibm.websphere.v85.core_1.0.200.v20170613_0418.jar failed on Read timed out.
.
.
.
Retry attempt 15 started
Read timed out
Unable to read repository at http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/updates/wdt/oxygen_comp/repository/plugins/com.ibm.websphere.v85.core_1.0.200.v20170613_0418.jar.
Read timed out
```

The download of the file always freezes after about 2.9 MB. The same problem occurs when trying to download the file in a browser. The resource is however downloadable via secured https.

I tried Oxygen and Oxygen1 versions of Eclipse.

How to fix it? Or at least, is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

The jar file that you mentioned is not available any longer.  It has been replaced by:

http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/updates/wdt/oxygen_comp/repository/plugins/com.ibm.websphere.v85.core_1.0.200.v20171214_0201.jar

I was able to successfully install WDT via Eclipse marketplace using Oxygen.